# JSON array deserialization -- is the order of elements always preserved?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, json, serialization

When deserializing a JSON array in C#/.NET, is the order of elements always preserved?

Edit: The library currently being used is .NET 3.5's System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer

Comment: Do you mean for an array in JSON format?

Comment: When you say array, do you mean a real array (`["foo", "bar", "baz"]`), or an object (`{"foo": 1, "baz": 2}`)?  Any sane implementation will preserve the order of arrays.  I would not expect the order of key-value entries in objects to be preserved (and it shouldn't matter, since the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says objects are an "unordered collection"), but some libraries will.

Comment: @Matt: The former is an array, the latter is an object. I suspect you're correct about only the former having its order preserved.

Comment: @Steven, right.  I'm checking because many people incorrectly call JavaScript objects "associative arrays."

Comment: @Steven/Matt: Yes, an array in JSON format (e.g., ["foo", "bar", "baz"]), not a JS/JSON object. I also believe the order should/would be preserved, but I wasn't able to find documentation of this specifically.

Comment: @Jordan, if you tell us what library you're using, we can scrounge the documentation.  But it's really so fundamental, I would assume it is preserved, and not worry about it.

Comment: I would think that it would have to be, as `["foo","bar","baz"]` should be equivalent to `{ 0: "foo", 1: "bar", 2: "baz" }`.

Comment: @Matt: I'm using .NET 3.5's System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer. I would think that, since ordered lists are part of the JSON standard, any sensible implementation would retain order, but this was questioned by someone recently, so I wanted to confirm.

Comment: @Matt: They *are* associative arrays. You can associate a value with a numeric or string key, with the former giving you a sparse numeric array while the latter results in an object, since `foo["bar"]` is the same as `foo.bar`.

Comment: @Steven, first of all, numeric keys are converted to strings.  Try `var o = {1:2}; o[2] = 3; for(var key in o){alert(typeof key);}`  Second, I understand why people bring that terminology over.  But the standard uses the term "object".  I think overall "associative array" tends to confuse people (especially beginners) into either using the `Array` type or thinking associative arrays have a length.

Comment: @Matt: Well, non-sparse arrays have a length, but an associative array (or object or whatever) is sparse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The JSON spec does specify that the order is preserved for arrays as they are an **ordered** collection of values: [JSON.org](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on implementation of your library of choice for the task. I your library documentation does not say anything on the matter, I would assume that it is implementation details and can not be trusted(can be changed in next version).